# AVR Library/Snippit for tracking date

Tags: c++, avr

Does anyone know of a library or good code snippit that can be used to store/keep track of time and date within an embedded environment (AVR MCU). I would like to be able to set a date and time and then update it using a 1hz pulse from one of my timers. I could write this code myself however I feel like there may already be something out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was taking the `time.h` library that was used by apple and adapting it slightly for my project as it was under the BSD licence. It can be found [Here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-583/include/time.h)

Answer (score 2):

Normally you would use a RTC for this because the 1Hz pulse of the AVR is not that precise. A normal way to do this is to make a time stamp of the current time and increase it every second. You can make a timestamp by using the method `mktime` although I'm not sure it's supported supported in the AVR libc. http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/mktime/ When you want to convert it back to 'normal' time you could use `ctime` for the printable version or `gmtime` for the `struct tm` version.

Comment: `time.h` is not included in AVR libc

Comment: Ah to bad :/ It was supported in AVR32 libc... suppose then he would need to use or port the Arduino Time lib indeed.

Comment: I have my async timer (timer 2) hooked up to a 32.768khz crystal and am prescaling by 128. As it is an 8 bit counter it fills after 256 intervals which is 1 second. As it is async it is not dependent on my processor clock. Looks like I will end up doing that and putting that up on the web. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

There is the [Arduino Time library](http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Code/Time). I never used it though.